# Sorting ArrayList using MyComparator Class

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap, comparator

I have a HashMap which I copy to an ArrayList and then I want to sort the entries in my List according to the bandwidth of each entry, the higher the bandwidth the first it should come in my list 
Here is what I tried

Main Class

```
   ArrayList<Signal> messages = new ArrayList<Signal>();
   messages.addAll(map.values());
   Collections.sort(messages, new MyComparator());
```

My Comparator Class

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Signal>{

@Override
public int compare(Signal s1, Signal s2) {
    if (s1.getBandwidth() > s2.getBandwidth() ) {
        return -1;
    } else if (s1.getBandwidth() < s2.getBandwidth()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

It does not sort my signal objects according to bandwidth ?

What I am doing wrong

**Problem Solved**

**Actually I was not setting the bandwidth before sorting it**

Here is the code Hope it will help some one

```
  public void createSortedSet(HashMap<String, Signal> map,
        final BufferedWriter buffwriter, long totalSize) {

    try {
        messages.addAll(map.values());
        for (Signal signal : messages) {
            signal.setBandwidth((signal.getSize() / (float) totalSize) * 100);
        }
        Collections.sort(messages, new MyComparator());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    createCSV(buffwriter, messages);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you see still same order or they are not sorted as per expected order ?

Comment: Does it sort your objects according to bandwidth in reverse order then?

Comment: It looks good actually :/ The only change I would make is changing the compare method to: `return s2.getBandwidth() - s1.getBandwidth();`

Comment: From a brief look, your compare method looks fine. Give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) where you put some hard-coded values in the map and print out something, showing that it's incorrect.

Comment: The one-line version of your function - `return -Integer.compare(s1.getBandwidth(), s2.getBandwidth())`

Comment: Since the problem was not with the code that was posted and/thus this question is unlikely to help future visitors and doesn't have an answer posted, you can and should probably delete it.